# How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, dynamic

How do you build and use dynamic sql in a MySQL stored procedure?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't believe MySQL supports dynamic sql.  You can do "prepared" statements which is similar, but different.

Here is an example:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM 
    -> 'select count(*) 
    -> from information_schema.schemata 
    -> where schema_name = ? or schema_name = ?'
;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared
mysql> EXECUTE stmt 
    -> USING @schema1,@schema2
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The prepared statements are often used to see an execution plan for a given query.  Since they are executed with the **execute** command and the **sql** can be assigned to a variable you can approximate the some of the same behavior as dynamic sql.

Here is a good [link](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html) about this:

Don't forget to deallocate the `stmt` using the last line!

Good Luck!

Comment: it isn't working when the `?` is in the place of the table name

Comment: Are you trying this via the mysql console? or using another method, if you are using this in code, your provider would need to support it.

Comment: Apparently, they're studying [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2793) for future versions.

Comment: @JaderDias use CONCAT to create the stmt, and only use `?` for non-meta information. e.g. : `PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl,' WHERE col = ? AND col2 = ?' );`

Comment: Also doesn't work on column names (as with table names) - see below answer/above comment instead.

Comment: That link to rpbouman.blogspot.com was super-helpful!

Answer (score 128):

After 5.0.13, in stored procedures, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Dynamic SQL does not work in functions or triggers. See [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for more uses.

Comment: Notice that you can only execute one statment each time. View https://stackoverflow.com/a/20374657/2630035 for an easier way

Answer (score 4):

**You can pass thru outside the dynamic statement using User-Defined Variables**

```
Server version: 5.6.25-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM 'select "AAAA" into @a';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

DEALLOCATE prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|AAAA  |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```