# Alter AUTO_INCREMENT value by select result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, auto-increment, alter-table

Basically what I want is a working-version of the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
AUTO_INCREMENT =
(
    SELECT
        `AUTO_INCREMENT`
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'another_table_name'
);
```

The error:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT =
```

The reason:

According to [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server
>   runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes
>   the counter for each table for the first INSERT to the table, as
>   described earlier.

This means that whenever I restart the server, my auto_increment values are set to the minimum possible.

I have a table called `ticket` and another one called `ticket_backup`. Both of them have a column `id` that is shared. Records inside the `ticket` table are available and can be claimed by customers. When they claim the `ticket` I insert the record inside `ticket_backup` and then I erase them from `ticket` table. As of today, I have `56 thousand` tickets already claimed (inside `ticket_backup`) and 0 tickets available. If I restart the server now and don't perform the `ALTER TABLE`, the first ticket I make available will have `id 1` which is an ID already taken by `ticket_backup`, thus causing me duplicate key error if I don't fix the auto-increment value. The reason for me to want this in a single query is to be able to easily perform the query on server startup.

Comment: There can be no earthly why you would want to do this.

Comment: There is no `SET` in the query. The MySQL syntax error messages contain the fragment of the query starting with the syntax error was detected. It says: "SET AUTO_INCREMENT = "

Comment: @Strawberry I'll be editing the main question to provide my reason.

Comment: @axiac I already fixed that, one of the answers below was about that, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Isn't it easier to run the two queries separately and use the client code to put the value retrieved using `SELECT` into the `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: @axiac I edited the question to reflect on why I'm trying to reach this goal. I wanted a single query so I could just automatically execute this script at server startup.

Comment: @strawberry I finished the edition including my reasoning.

Comment: Don't erase them. And certainly not for numbers as small and insignificant as 56,000. Instead see partitioning.

Comment: That said, one wonders why you didn't simply refer to the comments section of that page !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry I will take a deeper look at partitioning, but the reason to divide the tables wasn't about performance but rather make the reports easier to handle. The software works perfectly, this was my only known issue that wasn't expected. I didn't refer to that page comment section because their solution only covers triggers and Stackoverflow is a great place for developers to find fast solution.

Comment: Indeed, fixing the AI value only once at server start sounds better than running two queries in a trigger before every insert. I wonder if it's not possible to use a variable as a guard to avoid those selects run after the AI was fixed on the first insert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` INTO @AutoInc
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'another_table_name';

SET @s:=CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=', @AutoInc);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: You'll receive the bounty rep tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just upon quick glance, the error says it all. Syntax is incorrect

The syntax should adhere to:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=<INTEGER_VALUE>;
```

So looking at your query, remove the word "SET"

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT =
(
    SELECT
        `AUTO_INCREMENT`
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'another_table_name'
);
```

Comment: Although that does make sense and points out my lack of attention towards the proper way to use ALTER TABLE, your solution did not work. I guess for some reason I can't execute a DML statement inside a DDL statement. My code is a mere explanation to what I would hope to achieve.

Comment: Yeah looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741485/set-auto-increment-value-programmatically, looks like you'll have to do it via application code instead of SQL. Interesting :) So, maybe have a postinst script which does that?

Comment: This didn't work for me either but the answer from Saharsh did.

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
SET AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(a.AUTO_INC_VAL) FROM database_name.table_name a) )
```

if you want the current increment value or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
SET AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MIN(a.AUTO_INC_VAL) FROM database_name.table_name a) )
```

if you want the same initial INCREMENT VALUE

Comment: Neither of those options worked. Both of them gives me the same error as my statement.