# Nested MySQL select statements within the select clause

Tags: mysql, select

Is there a way to use a sub select statement, which returns a list of column names, to be used in the 'select expression' in an outer mySQL expression?

eg

```
select (
    sub select that returns a comma separated list of column names
) 
from table1;
```

In case your wondering how I get the comma separated list of column names, my sub select statement is somethign like...

```
SELECT group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
where table_name = 'table2' group by TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve this using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`, as explained here: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)