# Select all rows from all tables where column name equals given value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to select all the rows across all the tables where the column name matches a certain condition? I know how to select all tables that contain the given column name:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'customer_id'
```

Is there a way to join tables using the table name pulled out? For example, something that works as this (clearly incorrect) query tries to.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'customer_id') WHERE customer_id = 1
```

Comment: Not that I know of and in general, how would such a thing be implemented?  It is quite possible that some name is used for a column name in many different tables and that in each case the data type is different, which would seem to pose a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in plain SQL. You can't use the results of one query as a table/field name in an outer query. In your non-working example, you'd get a result set that looks like

```
+---------------+
| TABLE_NAME    |
+---------------+
| name_of_table |
+---------------+
```

from which you then try to filter on a `customer_id` field, which doesn't exist in the inner result.

You can build a query statement dynamically in a stored procedure, and execute that statement as detailed here: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure/5728155#5728155)

However, needing such dynamic queries is usually a sign of bad table design.