# Get the value at runtime

Tags: sql

Can anybody tell me how i can do this?

```
declare @test varchar(20)
set @test ='DatabaseName'

select b.* from @test.dbo.Table_Name
```

Here i am taking database from variable and using it in query.

Shall do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure ? Depends if we're talking about MySQL here or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @test varchar(20)
set @test ='DatabaseName'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select b.* from '+quotename(@test)+'.dbo.Table_Name as b'

exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: @AbhijithNayak "Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx

Comment: @AbhijithNayak "you can use quotename() to protect yourself against SQL injection" http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Exec` command or `Sp_executesql` because you are building dynamic query.

[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)