# Regular expression in MySQL / SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have for example:

```
tableAaa:
id | titleSSS
1  | sfdf
2  | sdfs

tableBbb:
id | titleUUU
1  | sfdf
2  | sdfs

tableCcc:
id | titleIII
1  | sfdf
2  | sdfs
```

etc, for example * 10.

Is possible make something like:

```
SELECT title* FROM table*
```

If yes, how?

EDIT: i dont want use UNION and do select from each table... These table is ~100. I would like make regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you'll have to list all column and table names manually:

```
SELECT titleSSS FROM tableAaa
UNION ALL
SELECT titleUUU FROM tableBbb
UNION ALL
SELECT titleIII FROM tableCcc
```

Note that you must use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` or otherwise you won't get duplicate rows in the output. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: i dont want make select from each table... these table is ~100

Comment: @PaulAttuck then generate this SQL statement in PHP

Comment: and how can i get name table beginning of "title" from MySQL to PHP?

Comment: @PaulAttuck `show tables where tables_in_<dbname> like 'table%';`

Comment: thanks +1, and how to show all name columns of these table? :)

Comment: @PaulAttuck `desc <table name>`

Answer (score 1):

The thing require by you is might not be possible you can do as below

```
SELECT title1 FROM table1
union
SELECT title2 FROM table2
union
SELECT title3 FROM table3
```

**OR**

You can make use of **DynamicSQL** to resolve your issue easily.
ans for you : [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: i know, but i would like make regular expression for this. I have these table 100

Comment: how to use DynamicSQL for this? :)

Comment: @Paul Attuck - here is link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure