# Use query result as table name

Tags: mysql

I want to delete records in parent table as well as child table using only one query.
I m having the child table name `CHILD1_TABLE` in the Parent table `PARENT_TABLE` in the field name of `TABLENAME`. The parent table contains more child tables.I want to delete only one record from one of the child table as well parent table.
The common field is `ID` in both child and parent tables.
I write my query like this,

```
DELETE PARENT.*,CHILD.* 
FROM PARENT_TABLE PARENT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLENAME FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID='CHILD1-001') CHILD 
ON PARENT.ID=CHILD.ID 
WHERE PARENT.ID='CHILD1-001'
```

But it not works. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Maybe some of the ideas here help - [How to have Dynamic SQL in mysql stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
DELETE PARENT.*,CHILD.* 
FROM PARENT_TABLE PARENT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TABLENAME FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID='CHILD1-001') AS CHILD)  
ON PARENT.ID=CHILD.ID 
WHERE PARENT.ID='CHILD1-001'
```

Comment: Change this to:
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT TABLENAME FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID='CHILD1-001') AS CHILD2)  AS CHILD

Comment: i have tried it on my pc and it works. Did you notice the difference i have changed the table aliases

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10157/discussion-between-sangeetha-krishnan-and-shayan-husaini)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: Thank you Euclides Mulémbwè.I am using MyISAM storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE PARENT.*,CHILD.* 
FROM PARENT_TABLE PARENT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TABLENAME FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID='CHILD1-001') AS a)  as child
ON PARENT.ID=CHILD.ID 
WHERE PARENT.ID='CHILD1-001'
```

I am not sure for this query but give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jason_vorhees. It gives the error Unknown table 'CHILD' in MULTI DELETE.