# nesting select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I am new to relational Databases... 
I want to list all data in many tables within the same DB.

I have a table that contain NAMES of other tables. Like this:

```
mysql> select * from CarKeys;


+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| Audi  |
| Honda |
+-------+


mysql> select * from Audi;

+-------+---------+--------+
| Model | NumDoor | Colour |
+-------+---------+--------+
| A4    | 4       | White  |
+-------+---------+--------+


mysql> select * from Honda;
+------------+---------+--------+
| Model      | NumDoor | Colour |
+------------+---------+--------+
| Civic      | 4       | White  |
| Civic      | 4       | White  |
| HomdaModel | 5       | Red    |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

But now,  I don't wanna be calling `select * from Honda` and `select * from Audi` seperately. 
I want a single command that will `select * from` all tables Named within `CarKeys` table

I tried this:
       `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CarKeys);`

but I got a this error message:
       `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`

how can I get all info for all tables within this Database? The name of the Schema I am using is `WebApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tables are haven't good relation,  you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM Audi
UNION
SELECT * FROM Honda
```

Result:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| Model      | NumDoor | Colour |
+------------+---------+--------+
| A4         | 4       | White  |
| Civic      | 4       | White  |
| Civic      | 4       | White  |
| HomdaModel | 5       | Red    |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a big problem in your SQL design. You souldn't call tables this way. Why wouldn't you create a single table for all your cars and add a column refering to the table containing the names ?

```
+-------+-------+
| ID    | Name  |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | Audi  |
| 2     | Honda |
+-------+-------+



+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| Model      | NumDoor | Colour | Brand  |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
| Civic      | 4       | White  | 2      |
| A4         | 4       | White  | 1      |
| Civic      | 4       | White  | 2      |
| HomdaModel | 5       | Red    | 2      |
+------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to used a **Stored Procedure**.

Use a **loop**, over `Carkeys.Name` stored it in `variable (v1)`

Now execute using **[Prepared Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)**

```
select * from v1
```