# How to change all table prefix in a single query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, prefix

I am pretty amateur in mysql..can you please tell me how can I change table prefixes of my whole database in a single query... I can do it manually, but its quite time consuming to change all the tables prefixes. Please help me out. Like isc_administrator_log to cus_administrator_log   means   isc_  to  cus_

I found these two solutions but do not understand either of them.

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '` TO `', 
TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`prefix_', TABLE_NAME, '`;' SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM `TABLES` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = "test";
```

and

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT('`', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME,
'` TO `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`prefix_', TABLE_NAME, '`')) AS q
FROM 
`information_schema`.`Tables` WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test';
```

Comment: Give us same example of **Input and Output**

Comment: Why not just do one, modify table statement in a text editor, copy and paste, then run the script.  Your question is interesting, however.

Comment: @Pete Bel i cant understand those queries hence i put the question..if u understand plz share ur views...i ran those queries..but in both case it returned NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **Dynamic SQL Query** For **MySQL 5.0.13**

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT 'RENAME TABLE ', 
             GROUP_CONCAT('', TABLE_SCHEMA, ''.'', TABLE_NAME,
             ' TO ', TABLE_SCHEMA, ''='.prefix_''', TABLE_NAME, '')) AS q
             FROM 
             information_schema.Tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test'';;'
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Got the Reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure/5728155#5728155)

Answer (score 2):

phpmyadmin : select database ; tab structure => Check all => (with selected list) select add prefix to table .

(is not query but it works)

Answer (score 1):

Both statements generate strings which happen to be SQL statements that you can then copy/paste at your prompt to rename your tables.

Just replace the following two strings with the actual values your need:

`prefix_` : the prefix you want to add

`'test'` : the name of the database containing the tables you want to rename

Both statements are almost identical, the only difference is that `information_schema` is not explicitely mentioned in the first statement. Therefore the first statement must be run from the `information_schema` database (issue `USE information_schema` beforehands).

Comment: after giving this it returned RENAME TABLE `iblue_bh_db`.`bh_admin` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_admin`,`iblue_bh_db`.`bh_album` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_album`,`iblue_bh_db`.`bh_banner` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_banner`,`iblue_bh_db`.`bh_blog` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_blog`,`iblue_bh_db`.`bh_blog_catagory` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_blog_catagory`,`iblue_bh_db`.`bh_blog_tags` TO `iblue_bh_db`.`blue_bh_blog_tags`