# How to display data of dynamically selected column

Tags: sql, dynamic-data

I have a table with 20 columns. I am dynamically selecting a column according to the user input and then want to display the selected column with it's data. Here is the code I wrote but the issue is I am getting column name as the data for the selected column. Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Getreport
@Subject [varchar](10),
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
--Query to generate report

SELECT FirstName, LastName, @Subject FROM Student
```

Comment: You need [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: @user2989408 I am getting this error "Incorrect syntax near 'PREPARE'."

Comment: Actually because its a stored proc, try the solution in the second answer of the previous link.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. See if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL:

EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ' FROM Student')

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure should look something like. [Similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) is shown here.

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT FirstName, LastName, ', @Subject, ' FROM Student');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```