# Inserting Into a table using Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

My problem is I am trying to insert into a table by using 2 where statements in my Sql Code.

My code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String"))
{
   conn.Open();

   using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO AssignPlan
         (Reps, Sets, WeightOrTime, Date, MemberId, ExerciseId) 
         Select @Reps, @Sets, @WeightOrTime, @Date, 
         Members.MemberId From Members Where Members.Username = @Username, 
         ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseId From ExerciseDisplay 
         Where ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseName = @Exercise", conn))
   {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reps", txtReps.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sets", txtSets.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeightOrTime", txtWeight.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", lblRegistered.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Exercise", txtName.Text);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");
   }

   conn.Close();
```

Any ideas on how to rephrase my SQL statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Easiest solution is to [create a unique constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) on the columns that should be distinct.

Comment: You should explain what is the relation between users table and ExerciseDisplay table. As is this query is not a valid SQL

Comment: You can't have two from statements, you must join the Members table to the ExerciseDisplay table on a common field and then only use one Where statement.

Comment: The query is completely unclear to me. Are you trying to insert into two tables in one operation, or are you trying to insert into one table the parameter values as well as the results of a join between two other tables?

Comment: Although I appreciate the enthusiasm on `using` statements and parametarized queries... I feel it is a sad day when this gets you 3 upvotes ;)  That being said, you need to join the tables.  This query will not work as is.

Comment: Sorry guys I probably was a bit vague but the below code works. Thanks  for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there's no relationship between Members and ExerciseDisplay you could do a cross-join and filter the results:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    " INSERT INTO AssignPlan " + 
    " (Reps, Sets, WeightOrTime, Date, MemberId, ExerciseId)  " + 
    " Select  " + 
    " @Reps, @Sets, @WeightOrTime, @Date, Members.MemberId, ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseId " + 
    " From Members, ExerciseDisplay  " + 
    " Where ExerciseDisplay.ExerciseName = @Exercise " + 
    " AND Members.Username = @Username ", conn))
```

or, since you're just pulling one value from each table, a subquery should work as well:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    " INSERT INTO AssignPlan " + 
    " (Reps, Sets, WeightOrTime, Date, MemberId, ExerciseId)  " + 
    " Select  " + 
    " @Reps, @Sets, @WeightOrTime, @Date, " +
    " (SELECT MemberId FROM Members WHERE Username = @Username), " +
    " (SELECT ExerciseId FROM ExerciseDisplay WHERE ExerciseName = @Exercise) "  
    , conn))
```

But that requires that each subquery only returns one value.

Comment: I would be interested to know if the presence of the WHERE could help to reduce the effects of the Cartesian product of the two tables.