# MySQL - Variables in Query similar to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have this code on my PHP:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM ponteved_admincs." . $_GET['servidor'] . " WHERE auth = '" . $_GET['auth'] . "';UPDATE ponteved_foroipb.members SET member_group_id = 3 WHERE member_id = '" . $_GET['foroid'] . "' LIMIT 1";
mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
```

This code removes from DB the specified user passed by a GET, and changes user groups on the IPB forum. Is there a way to do variables in a query if I try to do it on a MYSQL EVENT?

I have this on a MysqlEVENT:

```
DELETE FROM ponteved_admincs.27015 WHERE DATE(vencimiento) <= DATE(NOW())
```

Example that I'd like to do, but I don't know:

```
var @getuserid = SELECT `foroid` FROM `27015` WHERE `auth` = 'Green';
DELETE FROM ponteved_admincs.27015 WHERE DATE(vencimiento) <= DATE(NOW())
UPDATE ponteved_foroipb.members SET member_group_id = 3 WHERE member_id = '@getuserid'
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You should prepare the statement first, otherwise you are open to SQL injection. @MarkBaker lol

Comment: what exactly you want to do please explain

Comment: [Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: I'm only the person that have access to the form.
I'm trying to remove expire data to db automatically, and change user groups on the related forum, but I need the user ID of the forum (found in a column).

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a mysql function / stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, via Mysql Event automatically.

Comment: You can use CONCAT to build up a string which you then use prepare to use the string as a statement, then execute the statement. Check the 2nd response to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure