# Using a query to determine table name

Tags: mysql

A fairly terribly named question, sorry!

So I have a table that gives me a *listid number* which relates to the end of a table name. How can I join to that table?

My query gives me `rellistid` and `relsubscriberid`

The `relsubscriberid` is in a table that is named `oempro_subscribers_XXX` where `XXX` is the `rellistid`

How can I search for that `subscriberid` in that table?

This isn't my database, this is a database for a web-based marketing system called Oempro and I've not been able to find a direct link in any other tables.

Schema:

```
LinkTrackID int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
RelOwnerUserID  int(11) NO  MUL     
RelCampaignID   int(11) NO  MUL     
RelEmailID  int(11) NO  MUL     
RelAutoResponderID  int(11) NO  MUL     
RelListID   int(11) NO  MUL     
RelSubscriberID int(11) NO          
LinkURL text    NO          
LinkTitle   varchar(250)    NO          
ClickDate   datetime    NO
```

Comment: share your table schema

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea; you shouldn't have hundreds of separate subscribers tables, you should have one. Then your query becomes simple, you'd just need a WHERE clause.

Comment: That's a very bad schema. You should have a single table `oempro_subscribers` with an additional column to contain the `XXX`.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, yes it is a terrible schema. It's not my database, it's an application's database that we use... it's horrible and I hate it!

Comment: How many `oempro_subscribers_XXX` tables do you have? If the number is limited (and stable), you can use the solution I added in the comment to my answer.

Comment: @jcaron unfortunately the system creates a new table for every list (which is one per marketing campaign)  It's not pretty...

Comment: Then I only see the option of doing it through 2 separate SQL requests, with the second one "generated" based on the result of the first.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do it in SQL. So you'll have to do the first query, then generate the second query using the results of the first (how exactly you do this depends on the language being used).

Note however that IMHO, that's a very bad schema. You should have a single table `oempro_subscribers` with an additional column to contain the `XXX`.

Comment: Note that if the number of `oempro_subscribers_XXX` is limited, you can do: `SELECT 'XXX1' AS xxx,* FROM oempro_subscribers_xxx1 UNION ALL SELECT 'XXX2' AS www,* FROM oempro_subscribers_xxx2` etc. This requires the number, order and type of the columns of all such tables to match (or you'll have to explicitly list the columns). You can then join/select based on the new `xxx` column. You can also create a view for this to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use prepared statement, like described here: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

... but I really think you need to fix your schema.

Comment: If it were my database I would sort the schema, unfortunately it's a marketing system called OEMPro

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to use some kind of Dynamic SQL.

I don't think you'll be able to do it one step.

1) You can use the results of the first query to get the table name.
2) You can use that result to generate the query "on the fly" against the second table.

Check out the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html