# Table name as a variable

Tags: sql

I have to use a piece of software that once it runs an analysis it creates a table with a unique reference id. To access these results via SQL is a pain, so I am creating a template so that users can easily pass the results through into Excel.

The problem I have is that the table name is constantly changing. Is there a way of making the:

```
Select * From <variable>
```

possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (Mssql,oracle, MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with dynamic sql for example for t-sql it looks like

```
declare @tablename varchar(max),
        @sql varchar(max) 
set @tablename = 'tableName'
set @sql = 'Select * From '+@tablename

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Hi Parado, Thank you very much for the quick reply. I'm trying to implement your answer but @Tablename is not working. Do you know if this is not possible in dynamic SQL? `DECLARE @Table_Name NVARCHAR(max),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @Table_Name = 'SELECT Result_ID FROM #TmpResult WHERE ResultsSetName = ''Company A'''
SET @SQL = 'Select * From '+@Table_Name

EXEC @Table_Name
EXEC(@SQL)`

Comment: Here `SET @Table_Name = 'SELECT Result_ID FROM #TmpResult WHERE ResultsSetName = ''Company A'' ' ` you set whole select statement not table name. You should set here table name for example SET `@Table_Name = 'Salary'` or from query `select @Table_Name = name from table ...`

Comment: Thanks Parado, I think it must be something to do with the quotations as I'm still getting an error `(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`

Comment: I've updated some table names but here's the whole thing `DECLARE @Table_Name NVARCHAR(max),
  @SQL NVARCHAR(max)

SET @Table_Name = 'SELECT Result_ID FROM #TmpEventSet WHERE ResultsSetName = ''Company A'' '
SET @SQL = 'Select * From [Analysis].[dbo].'+@Table_Name

EXEC(@SQL)
EXEC(@Table_Name)` Maybe I can't run two of these together as when I run them seperatly they work fine?

Comment: @Carlos80 This line `SET @Table_Name = 'SELECT Result_ID FROM #TmpEventSet WHERE ResultsSetName = ''Company A'' ' ` doesn't return table name. After hits code `SET @SQL = 'Select * From [Analysis].[dbo].'+@Table_Name  ` the SQL value will have `Select * From [Analysis].[dbo].SELECT Result_ID FROM #TmpEventSet WHERE ResultsSetName = ''Company A''` So it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Doh! I see this now, does this mean that what I'm trying to do is not possible? Essentially I have a temp table that concatenates two columns to create the newly created table name. I was hoping that I could select * from based on the concatenated value held in my temp table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58606/discussion-between-parado-and-carlos80).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called Dynamic SQL:

**SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'Select * From ' + @yourTableNameVariable
EXEC(@sql)
```

**ORACLE** [source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130)

```
sql_stmt := 'Select * From  ' || yourTableNameVariable;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
```

**MySQL** [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@yourTableNameVariable);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Disclaimer**
I am only proficient in SQL Server. The other examples are modifications of code found as defined in the **[source]** next to the DB engine's name.

Comment: Assuming that the OP is using MSSQL

Comment: @Arion You are right, so i added samples of the other two main DB engines. I hope OP is not using FireBird...