# Mysql store procedure get table name as parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql procedure that inserts a row to a table. Is it possible to pass the name of the table as a parameter?

I tried and got an unknown table exception.

EDIT:

my procedure is called from insaid a trriger:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `blabla`(tableName VARCHAR(255), var1 VARCHAR(255), var2 VARCHAR(255), var3 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tableName 
            SET
                var1 = var1,
                var2= var2,
                var3= var3;

END
```

the error: ERROR 1146: 1146: Table 'xxx_xx_admin.tableName' doesn't exist

Comment: Post what you tried...

Comment: Show your query and error you are getting

Comment: Check: [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only if you use dynamic SQL to build your SQL. MySQL implements this using [PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/prepare.html) and [EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execute.html).

See [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)
and
http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html