# How to return a column value as text from a subquery in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty new to MySql and this might seem like a stupid question, but i can't seem to find the answer anywhere.
I have two tables that I'm working with.
The first table contains a lot of columns filled with Integer values.
such as:    `No_of_Landlines  No_of_mobiles`
The second table is a Rule Table which contains a rule name followed by the actual rule.
Eg:

```
 ID    RuleName    Rule
  1    Example     No_of_Landlines > No_of_Mobiles
```

The query that i want to run is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DemoTable 
WHERE (SELECT Rule from RuleTable WHERE ID=1)
```

What i want it to do is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DemoTable 
WHERE No_of_Landlines > No_of_Mobiles
```

When i run the first query against my database, it returns empty because the value of the rule being fetched from the Rule Table is a string and not a column name that I want, unlike query two under it.
How do I make the values of the string being returned into column names and execute the entire query?

One of my friends who's good with `MSSQL` suggested this:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(4000)
SET @a=(SELECT Rule FROM RuleDB WHERE ID=1)
print @a

EXEC('SELECT * FROM DemoTable WHERE ' + @a)
```

I tried this in `MSSQL` and it does work the way I want it to.
Is there a way to achieve this in **MySql**?

Comment: Take a look at this SO post on how to use dynamic SQL in MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXECUTE command, [this is a link to the syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html)! .

Here is an example script:

```
SELECT @Q:= CONCAT('SELECT * FROM DemoTable WHERE ', Rules.Rule) FROM Rules     WHERE ID=3;
PREPARE stq FROM @Q;
EXECUTE stq;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stq;
```

In this script you create que query you want to execute in the variable @Q concatenating part of the query with the result of the rule you are fetching from the *Rules* table.

Then you prepare the statment, execute and deallocate.

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables in MySQL and use them the same way you used them in MSSQL.

The complete documentation can be found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html