# MySQL split string and then select

Tags: mysql, string, split

I've searched the interwebs and SO for a solution to what I'm trying to do but can't find said solution so...

I have a stored procedure that accepts one parameter, my_str. If my_str has spaces within the string (let's say  "now is the winter of our discontent"), I want to iterate through that string and generate a WHERE clause. IE if my_str = "now is the winter of our discontent", I want to generate something like the following:

```
SELECT id, title, author
FROM my_table
where (my_content like '%now%'
    or my_content like '%is%'
    OR my_content like '%the%'
    OR my_content like '%winter%'
    OR my_content like '%of%'
    OR my_content like '%our%'
    OR my_content like '%discontent%'
);
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to do the splitting/sql-building inside your stored proc? or in some client app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sql string and use PREPARE

```
    SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT id, title, author FROM my_table where (my_content like '%", REPLACE($myStr, " ", "%' OR my_content LIKE '%"), "%');");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Read this for more info: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)