# Loop & increment values on both sides of an expression

Tags: mysql, loops, variables, set, increment

My goal is to create a series of "SET" commands using the LOOP command:

```
SET @value_title_1 = value_1
SET @value_title_2 = value_2
...
SET @value_title_99 = value_99
```

the numbering (counter) needs to increase by equal amount of 1 on both sides of the SET command.

The following is a representation of the code I am working with and also includes the "dummy entry" (you will recognize this by SET concat on the LEFT side of the equasion, which is the tricky part)

```
delimiter $$ 
 CREATE PROCEDURE set_values_table()
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
 DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;

simple_loop: LOOP
    SET counter=counter+1;
    SET concat('@value_title_',counter) = concat('value_',counter);
IF counter = 99 THEN
 LEAVE simple_loop;
 END IF;
 END LOOP simple_loop;
 SELECT "procedure completed!";
 END$$

 delimiter ;

call set_values_table();
```

Unfortunately, the SET concat(...) yields a syntax error. Any direction or step closer to solution would be much appreciated! Or is there another way to accomplish the same result as stated above?

Comment: Hi Stan, it's a little unclear what you're trying to do in your question. Do you want to build up a string containing all the `SET` statements? I don't think you can use SQL the way you want using a string in place of the variable identifier.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that what you want to do (the way you want to do it), just isn't possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @TZHX - Ravinder below came pretty close, however, the output is relayed as a non-executable string only. I need each of the created statements to actually truly "SET" the value as given so I could retrieve each of them separately right after with SELECT commands.

Comment: Stan: maybe if you build on Ravinder's script (which is along the lines of what I was thinking could be done) and take a look at the [question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) about running dynamic sql statements in a procedure, you'll be able to do something with it? I'm not a regular user of mysql I'm afraid so I'm not sure if they'd stay in scope after it's executed in that way. HTH.

Comment: Indeed! TZHX I was able to combine what you suggested. And... I got it working!! I will go ahead and mark the answer accepted by @Ravinder and extend kudos to you for directing me to the last missing piece! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET` command can only be used to set values for *variables* using their names, but not *expressions*.

If I understand correct, you must be trying to generate `99` *SET* commands to set values for `99` variables and use the same output in your code.

You need part of your SP body part changed as below (I used loop count as 5):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
  set @result := '';

  simple_loop: LOOP
    -- SET concat('@value_title_',counter) = concat('value_',counter);
    set @result := concat( @result, '\nset @value_title_', counter );
    set @result := concat( @result, ' := value_', counter, ';' );
    IF counter = 5 THEN
      LEAVE simple_loop;
    END IF;
    SET counter=counter+1;
  END LOOP simple_loop;
  -- SELECT 'procedure completed!';
  SELECT @result as result;
END;
```

You can check the output as below:

```
mysql> select @result as res\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
res:
set @value_title_1 := value_1;
set @value_title_2 := value_2;
set @value_title_3 := value_3;
set @value_title_4 := value_4;
set @value_title_5 := value_5;
```

You can use the `@result` variable value as desired.

Comment: This is much appreciated, @Ravinder ! However, my intention is for these SET commands to actually "execute" and truly "set" the values as given. In other words, I should then right after be able to run the SELECT command, such as mysql> select @value_title_1; but this gives me NULL as return, not the actual value ("value_1") it was just assigned. Would that be possible somehow?