# Concat select query with like %string%

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Here is the simplified query that doesn't work.

```
SET @abc = CONCAT('%','string','%');

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE ',@abc);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I need to use CONCAT with SELECT because there lots of other variables in real query.

Real query works fine when I use some simple **COLUMN=xyz** in **WHERE** clause. But nothing works when I try to use **LIKE %xyz%**...

Comment: Let me guess, do you use instead of `'string'` another column name?

Comment: The feature you require is "dynamic SQL" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
SET @abc = CONCAT('"%','string','%"');

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * 
 FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE ',@abc);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Check the first line I have added " to show @abc like "%string%"

Comment: How does this prevent against SQL injections?