# Getting the sql queries for node pg module

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am working with the pg module for node. I am trying to get some rows from different tables. Often times i get an error in my tests when accessing rows because the query came back empty. In that case i would like to get the query with parameters inserted in the console so i can paste it to pgAdmin and see what is wrong easier.

I tried searching for it in the pg docs but couldnt find anything.

Is there a way to output the queries?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101141/postgresget-executable-query-from-query-with-parameters/36109865#36109865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Vitaly's comment and his library [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) I was able to print out the statements like described by him in this answer:

[get executable query from query with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101141/postgresget-executable-query-from-query-with-parameters)

Thank you Vitaly.

Comment: Since you are developing for Node.js + PostgreSQL, you can switch over to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) completely, and not just for query formatting ;)