# Execute same query in several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How can execute in mysql a query that executes the sentence in several tables if exist. For example:

I can have the following tables: w_extra_content, w_extra_content_gl, w_extra_content_dn.

Is there any way to run something like:

```
update name = "example" from w_extra_content * where name = "old_example"
```

and that the query is executed on all tables that match the name?

In the tables only varies the final completion but you may not know that termination is in the database.

It can only be in mysql.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL, info [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5728155/2144048)

Comment: Why do you have several tables, so similar?

Comment: It's easy by using trigger.

Comment: i need to get the table names in mysql and for that table execute the same query. is this possible using only mysql to get the table names and a loop to execute the query in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below query

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @query := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ','update ',TABLE_NAME,' set name = \'example\' where name = \'old_example\'') 
                    SEPARATOR ';')
              FROM 
              ( SELECT Table_NAME
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'w_extra_content%') tab);    
     PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt ;
     SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1024;
```

Comment: thanks for the response but when i execute the code mysql tells me: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Comment: SELECT Table_NAME
              FROM information_schema.tables 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'w_extra_content%'       run this query and check if you are getting any rows

Comment: yes, the query returns the following rows: w_extra_content, w_extra_content_gl, w_extra_content_nd

Comment: consulta SQL:


    
     PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update  w_extra_content  set nombre = 'example' where nombre = 'old_example'' at line 1

Comment: modified quiery please check

Comment: the problem is the char (') before update. how can i delete this char. if i copy the query and delete the ' near update works but i don't know how can i do this here : (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ','update ',TABLE_NAME,' set nombre = \'example\' where nombre = \'old_example\'')

Comment: Did you run my updated query? If still the problem persists write select @query before prepare stmt and run up to this select. Copy query from output and run it

Comment: i can't run the query that you posted, mysql tells that have an error on line 1, but if i copy (update  w_extra_content set name= example where nombre = old_example) and i execute it works fine. i don't know where is the problem because i think is ok. thanks