# Find all tables whose values for a column are always the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have lots of tables named `item1`, `item42`, etc. (there are "holes" in the numbering). All tables have the same columns. In particular they have a column called `Value`.

How do I retrieve in mySQL the list of all tables for which all their tuples have the same value for `Value`?

```
SELECT Count(Value) FROM item1 GROUP BY Value;
```

allows to find the number of different values in `Value` for a table.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'
```

allows to find all the tables I want to go through.

How do I combine those to get the list of tables for which that count is strictly greater than 2?

(**I am not asking whether this database structure is good or bad, it is what it is.**)

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing the same entities in multiple tables.  Parallel table structures are usually a sign of problem with the data modeling and lead to issues with querying.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did you even read the last line? I have no control over the structure.

Comment: Can you use dynamic SQL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: Yes, did read it (and would have even without the bold).  That is really the right solution if the database is going to be used effectively.  Barring that, you could create a view to do a `union` of all the tables.

Comment: @NevilleK Possibly in a procedure.