# Conditionally showing part of a query in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I have a MySQL query that I build in php but want to move into a stored procedure.  The entire query is good to move into the sproc, except for one complication:  In php, depending on a condition, I add a "`HAVING` ......" as the last line.  Is it possible to do a condition, case, etc. to build a query in a similar way?

For example:

```
PROCEDURE `GeyMyItems`(
    IN query VARCHAR(100)
    )
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table a
    JOIN another_table b ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE my_column = 'this_value'

    IF (query = 'abc')
       HAVING a.my_value = '123';

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I know the syntax of the `IF` is probably wrong, but I'm just showing what I'm trying to do.  Is there a better way to do this?

The only fall back I can think of is to maybe take care of the `HAVING` portion in php.  Just don't include it at all in the SQL, and when I am building my object/array, I can just filter there in my `while` loop.  But I'd like to see how I can utilize a stored procedure for something like this, if at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.0 and later, it's pretty easy.

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetMyItems`(
    IN query VARCHAR(100)
    )
  BEGIN
    -- Here you construct your SQL
    SET @s = 'SELECT 1';

    IF query = 'abc' THEN
       SET @s = CONCAT( @s, ',2');
    END IF;

    -- Here you execute it.     
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This was [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure).

Comment: Yes, that makes total sense.  Build the queries through variables.  Then execute it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

to your where clause add this:

```
and 
(
(query = 'abc' and a.my_value ='123')
or query <> 'abc'
)
```

Comment: Makes sense for easy conditionals.

Comment: To hande the use case where query is null, you should use "or ifnull(query,'') != 'abc'".