# Creating MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to write a function that looks for a value assigned to its configuration in a parent-child tree, if the value is null or empty it looks one level up for the value.
I am currently getting syntax errors when trying to create the function.
This is what i have so far,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `db`.`Configuration`(
    `ColumnName` VARCHAR(128),
    `CID` INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE Config VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE Parent INT;

    WHILE (@Config IS NULL OR @Config = "") DO
        SELECT @ColumnName INTO @Config, `ParentID` INTO @Parent FROM `Table` WHERE `ID`=@CID;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN CONCAT(@Config, '::', @Parent);
    END ;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting the following error when I try to add the function:

## 1327 - Undeclared variable: ParentID

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Always include errors you receive  in your post.  They're very meaningful so make sure you paste them verbatim.

Comment: You need insert into.. select as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error message in the question because you have multiple `into` clauses, whereas according to mysql manual on [select ... into ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) you can only have one. So, to get rid of this specific error message you nee to rewrite your select statement as:

```
SELECT @ColumnName, `ParentID` INTO @Config, @Parent FROM `Table` WHERE `ID`=@CID;
```

However, there are some further issues with your code:

1. `varname` and `@varname` do not refer to the same variable. The first one is either a function / stored proc parameter or local variable, while the 2nd one is a user-defined variable. In your code you must remove the `@` from the variable names.
2. You cannot use a variable in place of a field name in an sql statement. You must use dynamic sql with prepared statements to achieve this. See the following SO question on how to this: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)
3. You do not overwrite `CID` parameter in your while loop. This means that if the first iteration the configuration will remain null, then you have an infinite loop. You should change the value of `CID` in your loop.

I cannot guarantee that there are no further errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your function:

- You are using `SELECT...INTO` incorrectly. When selecting multiple values you should only use `INTO` once. For example `SELECT a,b into @a,@b FROM...`
- You are using user-defined variables with similar names to your function parameters, but they are not the same thing. In your code `CID` and `@CID` are different. I suggest using standard naming prefixes to clarify this: for example use `p_` for function parameters and `v_` for local function variables. You shouldn't need to use user-defined variables at all.
- Your `WHILE` loop is bound to lead to infinite loops since the query criteria never changes. If it returns NULL or empty string once, it will keep returning them forever.

Here's a quick rewrite to address the above issues. I'll leave it to you to implement the `WHILE` loop correctly:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `db`.`Configuration`(
    p_column_name VARCHAR(128),
    p_id INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_config VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE v_parent INT;

    SELECT p_column_name,`ParentID` 
    INTO v_config, v_parent 
    FROM `Table` 
    WHERE `ID`=p_id;

    RETURN CONCAT(v_config, '::', v_parent);
    END ;
//
DELIMITER ;
```