# How to get Count from a Result of MySql Query where each Result is a Different Table itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I've a ResultSet of a Mysql Query something like this :-

```
select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) from category
```

which is returning Results something like this :- -

**MovieComedyMovies
 CarsSportsCars
 ShowsComedyShows**

These 3 results are different tables itself.
 I want to perform Count() on these tables which I'm getting in results that is- to check whether these tables contains any data or not.
P.S -  I'm using MySQl 5.6

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Suppose  **MovieComedyMovies** table has 10 records & **CarsSportsCars**  has 20 records.  So what I'm looking for is to get **10**  , **20**  from my initial query. I think, I need to create some kind of Procedure to loop through each result and get count.

Comment: Set up and use prepared statements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your comment correctly you can write a subquery on `select` clause, like this.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MovieComedyMovies) AS MovieComedyMovies,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CarsSportsCars) AS CarsSportsCars
```

But from your question, you might want to do this.

`CASE WHEN` with `SUM` function.

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN concat(category_name,subcategory_name) = 'MovieComedyMovies' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN concat(category_name,subcategory_name) = 'CarsSportsCars' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from category
```

**Edit**

From your comment I guessed you can try this.

```
select concat(category_name,subcategory_name)，count(*)  
from category
Group by concat(category_name,subcategory_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @D-Shih , However What I'm looking for is -  to get **count()** result of the tables which I'm getting from my -->  **select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) from category** Query.  So far what I've tried is --  **select count(*) from (select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) from category)**

Comment: @sumit did you try my second query? I guess it will be work. Or you can put some sample data and expect result,.

Comment: The Problem here is I don't know how many results  
**select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) from category**  
going to return &  the results keeps on Changing. Thats the reason it's quite difficult to implement second Query.

Comment: I edit my answer you seem add `group by` and Alisa name can make your expect.

Comment: I'm getting an Error :--   
**Unknown column 'grp' in 'field list**'

Comment: I appreciate your efforts mate but seems today isn't quite a productive day for me. Anyways Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying your example query for historical purposes:

```
select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) from category
```

Assuming that's the query that still draws data:

```
SELECT count(Name) as Total, Name 
FROM (
       select concat(category_name,subcategory_name) as Name from category
     ) data
group by Name
```

Something along those lines. If you can build a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you might get a more specific answer.

Comment: thanks @Hector , the query is giving a error at 'data' - **unrecognize keyword**