# Retrieve rows from a table whose name you don't know, based on some criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

Is it mandatory to know the table name from which you want to fetch some data based on some criteria? For example, here I have a database with 20 tables containing the same columns, only different row data.

And I want to fetch some data, from outside, based on some criteria, without being able to know the table name. Is there some sort of query available, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM SOME TABLE WHERE ID = [randomnumber]
```

Comment: You need to specify the table name, however you could create a table containing the table name and matching criteria as columns. you could then use this table to get the required  data.

Comment: From what you've told me that would seem highly inefficient. Is there really no other way than to create temporary tables?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if all the tables were all in one? so u would just have to query from one table only

Comment: Is there a reason/ some specific condition based on which you are segregating your data?

Comment: Ryan Tan, actually that's what I should have done... sigh. It's a project I'm doing that has to "seem" complex. I could've easily merged them in one table. Ok anyway.
The reason is basically what I said above, Aaron.

Comment: hmm, the only way I could think of is first query the list of tables in the schema. `SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Tables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'` and then looop through all the tables with your condition and union all

Comment: Looks like you want something like [Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: What about creating a view that unions all of the tables, then having the application query the view? Wouldn't matter what table the necessary rows were in.....

Comment: Eric, that sounds like it would work. Could you maybe create an example? Thanks!