# How do I use the result from a SELECT statement in an ALTER COLUMN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the id returned from a SELECT statement as the default value in an ALTER COLUMN statement.

The select statement

```
SELECT id from table_a WHERE name='DISCOUNT';
```

The alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE table_b
  ADD COLUMN column_a SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT <id returned>
```

Comment: 'Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and user-defined functions are not permitted.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html . I wonder why you thought this was allowed. Perhaps a trigger instead.

Comment: You can use [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190776) for that.

Comment: Please provide an example of dynamic sql