# Incorrect integer value: 'H' for column 'variable' at row 2 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure in MySQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertFromJunction ()
BEGIN
DECLARE iteration INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE adjacentID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE junction VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 0;
SET junction = 'H';
SET iteration = 1;

loop2: LOOP
    SET adjacentID = (SELECT junction FROM Hybrid WHERE Hybrid_ID = iteration);

    IF iteration = 2 THEN LEAVE loop2;            --it can even be 1,3 etc
    END IF; 

    SET iteration = iteration + 1;

END LOOP loop2;

END;
$$
```

Now here is the hybrid table

```
Hybrid_ID  N    K    J    H
1          15   10   11   9
2          13   15   5    7
3          20   16   4    10
4          NULL NULL 3    NULL
5          NULL NULL 2    NULL
6          NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

So, basically what should happen is that the loop runs first time `adjacenID = 9`, then `iteration = 1+1=2`.

Then loop runs second time `adjacentID = 7` and loop should terminate (from IF). But there is an error and it is when the `SET` staement is executing.

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'H' for column 'adjacentID' at row 2
```

What is being done wrong. I checked all the data types too.

The error persists even when termination condition is set to `iteration = 1` which make me suspicious because there is no point of `row 2` in that case.

Comment: In `SELECT junction FROM Hybrid WHERE Hybrid_ID = iteration` both `junction` and `iteration` are variables. `junction` is set to `'H'` above. You try to put this value to `adjacentID` which is INTEGER, so implicit convertion applied. `'H'` cannot be converted to numeric, so error occures. Why you're surprized? PS. Your procedure is not recursive.

Comment: So i presume in the original somehting else happens with junction, trying to switch the culumn that is selected over the iterations. But this isn't dynamic sql, so you always get the value of junction, 'H'

Comment: @Akina so how should I do it. Any suggestions

Comment: Provide the task itself - what operation the procedure must perform? Show desired output for "Now here is the hybrid table" values with explanations. Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure for dynamic sql in stored procedures in mysql

Comment: PS. Does `SET junction = 'H';` means that you want to select from column `H`?

Comment: @Akina yeah that's what was intended

Comment: If so then you need in dynamic Sql (prepared statement, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: @Akina @Turo I used `SET @adjacentID = 'SELECT ? FROM Hybrid WHERE Hybrid_ID = ?' `, `PREPARE stmt FROM @adjacentID`, `EXECUTE stmt USING @junction,@iteration` but it treats H as a string rather than column. Can you post the solution as an asnwer. Also I don't intend to display the result but only set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insertFromJunction ()
BEGIN
-- Initialize needed user-defined variables
SET @junction = 'H';
SET @iteration = 1;

loop2: LOOP
    -- Build query text
    SET @adjacentID = CONCAT( 'SELECT ',
                              @junction,
                              ' FROM Hybrid WHERE Hybrid_ID = ',
                              @iteration);
    -- Prepare and execute the query
    PREPARE stmt FROM @adjacentID;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    -- Debug exit
    IF @iteration = 2 THEN 
        LEAVE loop2;
    END IF; 
    -- increase iterator
    SET @iteration = @iteration + 1;
END LOOP loop2;

END
```

Comment: it works, but when I used `SET @adjacentID = 'SELECT ? FROM Hybrid WHERE Hybrid_ID = ?';` and then `PREPARE stmt FROM @adjacentID;`, the output was again string 'H' rahter than `7` which occurs under column H. I wonder why is that considering I only changed the format

Comment: @mr.loop Column name **CANNOT BE SUBSTITUTED FROM A VALUE**. Including parametrized value. It is a literal which is accepted as-is, literally. So you select not column named `H` but string literal with value `'H'`.

Comment: thanks, that's why dynamic sql was needed.