# Recursively or using loops to dynamically add columns to a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot

I could really use some help with the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to dynamically add columns to a query based on the number of times a user_id occurs in this example event_table.

So, this is the example event_table. Every time the user_id comes up, I want another column with CONCAT("event_", times_occured) added to the result.

| id | user_id | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 344 | 2021-05-25 |
| 2 | 25 | 2021-05-25 |
| 3 | 344 | 2021-07-06 |
| 4 | 344 | 2021-07-07 |
| 5 | 3245 | 2021-08-25 |
| 6 | 52 | 2021-09-14 |
| 7 | 52 | 2021-10-11 |

The query result should be formed this way.

| user_id | event_1 | event_2 | event_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 2021-05-25 | null | null |
| 52 | 2021-09-14 | 2021-10-11 | null |
| 344 | 2021-05-25 | 2021-07-06 | 2021-07-07 |
| 3245 | 2021-08-25 | null | null |

I'm not sure if this is possible, and if it is, do I need to use recursion or loops?

Comment: Which versions of mysql and mariadb are you on?

Comment: `SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(`event`) FROM table GROUP BY user_id`.  This will not add a column, but will create a comma-separated list in the second column with all te dates. (See: [group_concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat))

Comment: You could `GROUP BY user_id` and then select [GROUP_CONCAT(create_date SEPARATOR ',')](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). That way you get all the dates in one result column, but they can be easily seperated by the comma. It all depends on what you're actually doing with this.

Comment: This cannot be performed in a query. You need in stored procedure with dynamic SQL usasge for to solve your task.

Comment: @Luuk and KIKO Software Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for. I'm using this to analyse some data using Excel. And I needed it in a csv form anyway!

Comment: Just one addition on the question. It's not necessary but makes it a bit easier to work with; Can I create the header also using Concat with the events numbered from 1 to the max amount of occurences?

Comment: @DylanBrugman: short answer: When you use the function `GROUP_CONCAT()` you will only get 2 columns (according to MySQL). when you start counting the `,` then, according to CSV you will have more columns in the rows.   Other answer: It can be done when you use dynamic SQL, like Akina suggested. see: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)