# Delete foreign keys with dynamic table and constraint names in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Given a MariaDB table `customer`, which other tables have a foreign key constraint on, I'm querying those table names with the following statement:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'customer';
```

Now, I'd like to delete the foreign keys in all tables from the above query but I don't know how to do that. The result shall be something like the following, where `table_name` and `constraint_name` are variables representing the result of the above query.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name;
```

Comment: I think you need to do something with [DYNAMIC SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)

Comment: and   a cursor and a loop https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the necessary SQL statements using that query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, '` ',
  'DROP FOREIGN KEY `', CONSTRAINT_NAME, '`;'
) AS _sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'customer';
```

That will produce a set of strings. Execute each one as a new SQL statement.

Note I did not test this, so if I made any typos I'll leave them to you to fix. The above example should be enough for you to get started.