# Dynamically set a column in a query depending on a variable

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I tried to dynamically set a column in a query depending on a variable value but it doesn't work:

```
SET @variable1 = 'Foo1'
SELECT CASE
    WHEN @variable1 = 'Foo1' THEN MY_TABLE.FIELD1
    WHEN @variable1 = 'Foo2' THEN MY_TABLE.FIELD2
    ELSE @variable1 = 'Foo3' THEN MY_TABLE.FIELD3
END AS FIELD_TO_SELECT, MY_TABLE.ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID = 'Something';
```

What did i missed?

Comment: In your `SELECT` you are referring to three different variables (`@variable1`, `@variable2`, `@variable3`) - guessing you might just want `@variable1` in each case?

Comment: Also your else is wrong as it has noch comparison

Comment: And you probably need a semicolon after your `SET` statement

Comment: @RobEyre sorry, CTRL+C/CTRL+V typo. it's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just have 1 variable `variable1`. [You can do "prepared" statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure) .

Here is an example:

```
SET @variable1 = 'Foo1';

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',
    CASE
        WHEN @variable1 = 'Foo1' THEN 'FIELD1'
        WHEN @variable1 = 'Foo2' THEN 'FIELD2' 
        ELSE 'FIELD3'  
    END,
    ' AS FIELD_TO_SELECT, ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = ?'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING 'Something';
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Also see the under utilized [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) to simplify the prepared statement execution.