# Pull data from tables with different suffixes sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have multiple tables with the exact same structure (fields: date, id, revenue). Let’s imagine I have 3 tables, each one with 3 rows to make this simpler.

The only thing that changes between each table the is the suffix, for example:

Myserver.Mytable_name.05112021 (which we’ll call table 1)
Myserver.Mytable_name.06112021
(which we’ll call table 2)
Myserver.Mytable_name.07112021
(which we’ll call table 3)

What I want is to pull some fields in those tables such that I don’t have to specify the suffix

The result I expect should look as follows:

| Id | date | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | date_1 | revenue_1 |
| id_2 | date_1 | revenue_1 |
| id_3 | date_1 | revenue_1 |
| id_1 | date_2 | revenue_2 |
| id_2 | date_2 | revenue_2 |
| id_3 | date_2 | revenue_2 |
| id_1 | date_3 | revenue_3 |
| id_2 | date_3 | revenue_3 |
| id_3 | date_3 | revenue_3 |

How can I get the above result without using union nor union all?

This is important because my tables are created on a daily basis and I don’t want to be adding them manually within a CTE in order to get the data.

Thanks for your help!

Using union or union all is cumbersome in this case

Comment: How is this `UNION` _not_ the way to go here, this is straight up a union

Comment: Are the fields in the tables named the same or do they have suffixes as well?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Why do you have one table per day? Or 365 tables per year? Or 3650 tables for 10 years? Why can't you store all data in one table along with date?

Answer (score 0):

> This is important because my tables are created on a daily basis and I don’t want to be adding them manually within a CTE in order to get the data

Then you will need to dynamically generate the SQL. For a MySQL solution start down this path: [How To have Dynamic SQL in MySQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5728155/1690217)

The only other way to avoid this is to create some standard views that return the data from your tables, but have the process that created the tables re-create the views, then you could have a single query that does not need to be changed.

- Either way, some process will need to change the views or change the query to reference the new tables. Dynamic SQL is the usual solution inside the database, but otherwise you could generate the query at the application layer, which would be the same principal.

Looks to me like `Union` is perfect for this:

Start with the manual query:

https://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afd29a/2

Notice here that I have constructed a date column using the suffix of the table name

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('Mytable_name.05112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date"
     , `id`
     , `revenue`
FROM `Mytable_name.05112021`
UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('Mytable_name.06112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date"
     , `id`
     , `revenue`
FROM `Mytable_name.06112021`
UNION ALL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('Mytable_name.07112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date"
     , `id`
     , `revenue`
FROM `Mytable_name.07112021`;
```

I'm not aware of a function we can use in MySQL to return the table name of a given column reference, but if we are going to use dynamic or *prepared statements* then it doesn't matter.

First we can generate the above SQL using this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('", table_name, "',8),'%d%m%Y') as \"date\", `id`, `revenue` FROM `", table_name ,"`") SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') as Query 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name like 'MyTable_name.%';
```

Which returns this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('mytable_name.05112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date", `id`, `revenue` FROM `mytable_name.05112021` UNION ALL SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('mytable_name.06112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date", `id`, `revenue` FROM `mytable_name.06112021` UNION ALL SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('mytable_name.07112021',8),'%d%m%Y') as "date", `id`, `revenue` FROM `mytable_name.07112021`
```

So we can put all this together into a single SP, below is a full example you can follow

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Xiv7XtbhP7d2N5EdqsYg4/0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamicQuery()
BEGIN
SET @query = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('", table_name, "',8),'%d%m%Y') as \"date\", `id`, `revenue` FROM `", table_name ,"`") SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') as Query 
              FROM information_schema.tables
              WHERE table_name like 'MyTable_name.%');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TABLE `Mytable_name.05112021` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `revenue` decimal(10,2)
)//
CREATE TABLE `Mytable_name.06112021` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `revenue` decimal(10,2)
)//
CREATE TABLE `Mytable_name.07112021` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `revenue` decimal(10,2)
)//
INSERT INTO `Mytable_name.05112021` (`revenue`) VALUES
( 50.10 ),
(135.10),
(35.75 )//
INSERT INTO `Mytable_name.06112021` (`revenue`) VALUES
( 60.10 ),
(136.10),
(36.75 )//
INSERT INTO `Mytable_name.07112021` (`revenue`) VALUES
( 70.10 ),
(137.10),
(37.75 )//

CREATE PROCEDURE dynamicQuery()
BEGIN
SET @query = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT('", table_name, "',8),'%d%m%Y') as \"date\", `id`, `revenue` FROM `", table_name ,"`") SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') as Query 
              FROM information_schema.tables
              WHERE table_name like 'MyTable_name.%');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
```

---

```
CALL dynamicQuery;
```

| date | id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-05 | 1 | 50.10 |
| 2021-11-05 | 2 | 135.10 |
| 2021-11-05 | 3 | 35.75 |
| 2021-11-06 | 1 | 60.10 |
| 2021-11-06 | 2 | 136.10 |
| 2021-11-06 | 3 | 36.75 |
| 2021-11-07 | 1 | 70.10 |
| 2021-11-07 | 2 | 137.10 |
| 2021-11-07 | 3 | 37.75 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Xiv7XtbhP7d2N5EdqsYg4/0)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `UNION/UNION ALL` for this but there's a way you write the query once and edit wherever necessary afterward. You can use [PREPARED STATEMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statement-types) for that.

Here is an example:

```
SET @generatedQuery := NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
         INTO @generatedQuery
 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema='Myserver' AND
 table_name LIKE 'mytable_%';

/*Check the generated query*/
SELECT @generatedQuery;

PREPARE statement FROM @generatedQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

In the example above, you'll only need to focus on the query to generate the actual query. Let's say that you want to get only specific date ranges, then you can do something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',table_name,' WHERE date="2023-11-11"')) 
                 SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
         INTO @generatedQuery
 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema='Myserver' AND
 table_name LIKE 'mytable_%';
```

or maybe the database/server (table_schema) already change or the table_name prefix is now different, then:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
         INTO @generatedQuery
 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema='newserver' AND
 table_name LIKE 'myNewtableName_%';
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/17H2-NQr)